# What is the curl equivalent of this wget command?

Tags: shell-script, wget, curl

I'm trying to switch over part of a script from `wget` to `curl`. I have this command:

```
wget --output-document=dl.html --quiet --timeout=10 --tries=1 $URL
```

What's the `curl` equivalent of this?

Answer (score 3):

```sh
curl -o dl.html -s -m 10 --retry 0 "$URL"
```

Note: `--retry` is not really necessary, but I added it for completeness and because the default values might be set in an environment or a rc file.